# how to pass querystring in anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net, anchor

I want to pass query string in anchor tag but facing some error i.e "server tag is not well formed".
My code is:-

```
    <a href="EditUser.aspx?uid='<%# Eval("Userid") %>'" id="aa" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use:

`<a href='<%# Eval("Userid","EditUser.aspx?uid={0}") %>'>Text</a>`/pre>

If you remove `runat="server"` and single quotes before and after eval expression, your code will also start working

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href='<%# "EditUser.aspx?uid=" + Eval("Userid") %>' id="aa" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use code breaks with string text together for an attribute value for an element which is ran server side. Instead you can use `String.Format()` to form the same response, using single quotes.

```
<a href='<%# String.Format("EditUser.aspx?uid={0}", Eval("Userid")) %>' id="aa" runat="server" />
```